# How can I cast input JSON object to model class in Node.JS with TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I am writing my Node.js server using TypeScript and express framework. 
This is how my controller and route looks like:

```
  export class AuthController {

        public async signUpNewUser(request: Request, response: Response) {
        ...
    }
}
```

How can I receive a model class instead Request type like in ASP.NET ?
Something like:

```
public async signUpNewUser(input: SignUpModel, response: Response) {
```

Is this a good idea at all? I am not sure this is a common approach in the Node.JS
I just want to make sure I get the same model each time and write a code related to this model and not on dynamic JSON object.

My suggestion is to convert to strong type model at the beginning of the route, but I am not sure this is a good way.

Does somebody have a solution for such cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I receive a model class instead Request type like in ASP.NET

This was a perpetual pain to me in my projects (and at work), eventually we decided to build a custom router with its own default error handling and auth-header checks. The trick with this pattern is to keep it lightweight, because this *is* still express and middleware is where things should go - this wrapper just provides a way for us to cast the express request into a properly shaped type based on the middleware we actually use.

This is pared down example, the idea is that you can specify the shape of the req & res by passing an interface (or an inlined type shape) and have typescript enforce the return shape.

Wrapper class example:

```
import * as express from 'express';

export type ExpressMethods = "get" | "post" | "put" | "delete" | "patch";

export type JsonRouteInput<RequestBody, RouteParams, QueryParams> = {
  body: RequestBody;
  params: RouteParams;
  query: QueryParams;
};

export type JsonRouteHandler<
  RequestBody,
  RouteParams,
  QueryParams,
  ResponseBody
> = (
  request: JsonRouteInput<RequestBody, RouteParams, QueryParams>
) => Promise<ResponseBody> | ResponseBody;

export class JsonRouter {
  router = express.Router();
  private addHandler<M extends ExpressMethods>(
    method: M,
    ...middleware: express.RequestHandler[]
  ) {
    this.router.use(...middleware);
  }

  get route(): {
    [K in ExpressMethods]: <
      RequestBody,
      ResponseBody,
      RouteParams = never,
      QueryParams = never
    >(
      path: string,
      handler: JsonRouteHandler<
        RequestBody,
        RouteParams,
        QueryParams,
        ResponseBody
      >
    ) => JsonRouter
  } {
    const addables = {} as any;
    (["get", "post", "put", "delete", "patch"] as ExpressMethods[]).forEach(
      <RequestBody, ResponseBody, RouteParams = never, QueryParams = never>(
        method
      ) => {
        addables[method] = (
          path: string,
          handler: JsonRouteHandler<
            RequestBody,
            RouteParams,
            QueryParams,
            ResponseBody
          >
        ) => {
          this.router[method](path, async (req, res) => {
            try {
              const responseBody: ResponseBody = await handler({
                body: req.body,
                params: req.params,
                query: req.query
              });
              res.json(responseBody);
            } catch (err) {
              // do your standard error handling or whatever
              res.status(500).end("ow");
            }
          });
          return this;
        };
      }
    );
    return addables;
  }
}
```

And then using it

```
const jsonRouter = new JsonRouter().route.get<{ request: number }, { response: number }>(
  "/hello-world",
  req => {
    return { response: req.body.request + 1 }; // type-checked result
  }
);
```

This can definitely be taken one step further - I have some prototypes that allow us to semi-fluently build the shape of the request/response body. The goal with this strategy long term lets us generate a typescript rest client for the frontend, generate input-validation that matches the type we're using to annotate, and also enforce that the response is the right type - [example router using this strategy to build the type dynamically](https://github.com/Sammons/vertically-typed/blob/master/backend/src/routes/sample.ts#L14)

EDIT: To plug this example into an express server

```
const app = express();

// custom middleware goes here

app.use('/', jsonRouter.router);

app.listen(8000)
```

Comment: @neustart47 its a major pain point :). In most projects everything is typesafe and works great except for the contract between the API & the UI. Tons of bugs we (all programmers everywhere) have to suffer through because of it.

Comment: just one tiny question: I just started with node.js and I am not sure that I understand how to declare routes with your example. I am declaring my routes as I described at the beginning of this topic. Where should I paste your code with usage example? 
Probably, you have some repo with an example or any kind of topic with a tutorial? I started with express and this declaration looks new to me. Thanks

Comment: @neustart47 updated the answer with an example. You can mount routers under paths using `use`. Routers themselves can `use` other routers too - this gives a lot of flexibility - for example you can conditionally add middleware that authorizes users for a group of endpoints under `/admin` e.g. `app.use('/admin', adminAuthMiddleware, adminExpressRouter)`

Answer (score 1):

So you seem to have a couple different questions in there.  The core question is "how do I cast a JSON object to a specific type", but then you also ask if it's a good idea or not and if it's a common practice.

The answer to your first question is pretty simple, you can cast it in your route (or wherever) like so:

```
router.get('/whatever', (req, res) => {
   const signup: SignupModel = JSON.parse(req.model) as SignupModel;

   // Do whatever you want with the signup model
});
```

Now, your other questions are way more opinion-based.  If I'm being honest, I would say "don't use Typescript". :)  Joking aside, I don't know how to answer your opinion-based question (nor is it a good fit for this site)

Comment: thanks for your answer. Do I understand correctly that this is not a commonly used approach? For me looks like this approach looks more safety, is this make sense ? What's can be wrong with this approach ?

Comment: I am going to move all functionality to classes with interfaces, I would like to use DI pattern, so I am going to write interface with method with input model type like route has. That's why I need this

Comment: I can't speak for the whole community, but given that almost all of the nodejs documentation across most of the modules on npm are written for JavaScript, not TypeScript, I would assert that it's probably not that common.  As for what's wrong with it?  I'm not saying it's wrong per se, but having come from C# to node.js (JavaScript) I can say that I've never missed the strong typing over the last 9 years.  And looking at the other answer, that sure looks like a LOT more code to maintain.